# Knockout foreach can't see $index after if

Tags: knockout.js

I have code like that:

```
        <!-- ko foreach: Items -->
            <!-- ko if: $index() % 3 == 0 -->
                <div class="row">
                <h1 data-bind="text: $index()"></h1>
            <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="col-md-4 item">
                    <h1 data-bind="text: $index()"></h1>
                </div>
            <!-- ko if: $index() % 3 == 2 -->
                </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko-->
```

I just want to make rows with three items inside each of them. But `$index` value is only visible in first `if`. I don't understand why. Can someone help, please?

Comment: is your second `if` only closing the `</div>` tag?

Comment: Only firstone is working. After first `<!-- /ko -->` no more working `$index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout does not imperatively run through your template, but declaratively builds the DOM from your markup. So using an `ko if` virtual binding seperately for start/end tags won't work.

Similarly, you couldn't do this in html:

```html
<strong> Some <em> text that </strong> has jagged start/end tags. </em>
```

Replace `strong` and `/strong` with your `ko if` and `/ko if` and you'll get a feeling for why this doesn't work so well.

You need to find another way entirely to do what you want. Here's one:

```js
function Vm() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.Items = ko.observableArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]);
  
  self.GroupedItems = ko.computed(function() {
    var a = self.Items(), arrays = [], size = 3;
    while (a.length > 0) arrays.push(a.splice(0, size));
    return arrays;
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new Vm());
```

```css
.row { display: block; }
.col-md-4 { display: inline-block; padding: 5px; background: silver; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: GroupedItems -->
<div class="row">
  <h1 data-bind="text: $index()"></h1>
  <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
  <div class="col-md-4 item">
    <h1 data-bind="text: $index() + ' - ' + $data"></h1>
  </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<!-- /ko-->
```

This would also allow you to not return sub-arrays, but objects that contain the subarray as well as e.g. a group "name" that includes the index.

Funnily enough, I wondered about a similar issue before, and based on [feedback I got on CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82750/dynamically-adding-blocks-of-information-to-a-page) I decided to just use *one* row and dump all items in there, perhaps that's useful for your scenario too (though you seem to need a `h1` between rows).